# Is a closed set in a linear subspace of a normed space closed?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space and let $Y$ be a linear subspace of $X$ with the norm given by the restriction of the norm on $X$ to $Y$. Let $S$ be a closed set in $Y$. So is $S$ closed in $X$?

What if $S\neq Y$? Can I get $S$ is closed in $X$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in general. Suppose that $Y$ itself is not a closed subset of $X$. Now, take $S=Y$.

Comment: What if $S$ is a proper subset of $Y$? Can I get $S$ is closed in $X$? Thank you!

Comment: No. Did you think that $S=Y$ was the only way of building a counterexample? Do you want an example with $S\varsubsetneq Y$?

Comment: Ok I get it so $S$ is closed in $X$ if $Y$ is a closed linear subspace of $X$ right?

Comment: Yes. If $A$ is closed in $B$ and $B$ is closed in $C$, then $A$ is closed in $C$.